# Commit to master branch will sub branch will take the changes

Tags: git

i would like to know. I have a master branch. There is another branch create by a developer called branch A. Since i am owner of the repo, i plan to commit directly to the master branch. The developer is a collaborator. Will there be any impact to the Branch A? or my fix will be automatically applied to branch A? Is there impact during pull request. I am using git anyway

Comment: The developer of `branch A` will need to synchronize their work with the new state of the `master` branch.

Comment: Its called merging.  Branch A will be merged into master when the pull request is accepted.  There could possibly be a 'merge conflict' in which case branch A will have to have someone resolve the conflict before it can be merged with the master branch.

Comment: so during pull request approving time this conflict wil ltake effect. Is there a way to solve this?

Comment: @rhyta Normally it is the branch owner's responsibility to keep their branches up to date. They will either merge or rebase master. I'd suggest reading the Branching chapter of Pro Git. https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Branching-Branches-in-a-Nutshell

Comment: Git has no concept of a "sub-branch". In fact, a branch's *name* is mostly irrelevant, except of course that you need to spell it however you spelled it, in order to type it in. There's nothing special about the various branch names. (This is a slight overstatement: there are a few special things about the name `master`, but they are all pretty minor.)

Answer (score 0):

Those are two different branches - pushing commits to one branch will not affect the other unless you explicitly pull into it or rebase it on top of master.

Comment: So merging will fail right will not override the master? is there a way to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

> i plan to commit directly to the master branch ... Will there be any impact to the Branch A?

No.

> or my fix will be automatically applied to branch A?

No.

Comment: How to make my fix to auto applied to branch A. I need to explicitly commit to branch A as well?

Comment: That is not what you asked.